# Sending all aspx page as an e-mail body

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page that give an exam result. I would like to send copy of this page as an e-mail body. I did a lot of search about this situation but i can not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you can't do like this. But instead, what you can do is load data in some DataTable and create HTML body of the email by looping through the rows of that DataTable.
What I intend to say is you create email body string from the results and send that to wherever you want to send it.